# C++ Implicit Conversion from R-Value

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to define an implicit conversion operator that will move a wrapper type into the implicit type as such:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct SomeStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct AnyStruct 
{
    template <typename T>
    T& Get();

    template <typename T>
    const T& Get() const;

    template <typename T>
    operator T& ()&
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue conversion\n";
        return Get<T>();
    }

    template <typename T>
    operator const T& () const&
    {
        std::cout << "const lvalue conversion\n";
        return Get<T>();
    }

    template <typename T>
    operator T()&&
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue conversion\n";
        return std::move(Get<T>());
    }

    SomeStruct cheat = { 0, 0, 0 };
};

template <>
SomeStruct& AnyStruct::Get<SomeStruct>()
{
    return cheat;
}

template <>
const SomeStruct& AnyStruct::Get<SomeStruct>() const
{
    return cheat;
}

int main()
{
    AnyStruct s2;
    SomeStruct s4 = std::move(s2);
    static_cast<void>(s4);
}
```

The first implicit conversion works and calls the right cast operator `operator T&() &`. I would have expected the second implicit conversion to call the right cast operator `operator T() &&` and move `s2` into `s4`, but it calls the cast operator `operator T&() &` instead and actually copy the struct.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This whole issue looks like a problem with MSVC. This statement will copy construct: `SomeStruct s = std::move(a);` but this one will move construct: `SomeStruct s = std::move(a.Get<SomeStruct>());` MSVC never picks the rvalue cast operator in the first case.

Comment: ("Implicit conversion". There's no such thing as an implicit cast.)

Comment: How exactly did you observe that this example calls `operator T&() &` twice?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0563aa24973afbaa

Comment: Interesting, thank you, you've put me on the right direction I think. It might be something else.

Comment: Ok so I was able to reproduce it. I forgot to say that I had a third cast operator for const ref and that I'm using msvc. Here's the link: https://rextester.com/live/BMWM49568

Comment: Interesting enough, this code prints `rvalue conversion` on `gcc`, but `lvalue conversion` on `msvc`.

Comment: @sturcotte06 which version of MSVC are you using? I fail to reproduce this using your code above in VS 2015, 2017, or 2019…

Comment: 14.22 on my PC, in the cloud I'm not sure, but I could reproduce it with both versions.